# AVPlayer HLS not working on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have a custom view with AVPlayer in it that is embedded in table view cell. AVPlayer loads .m3u8 link. But the thing is, it works in simulator, but doesn't on physical device. Any ideas on fixes? Thanks in advance.

```
class CameraView: UIView {

var player: AVPlayer? {
    get {
        return playerLayer.player
    }
    set {
        playerLayer.player = newValue
    }
}

var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
    return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
}

override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}
private func presentNewStream() {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: self.pathToStream)!)
    let keys: [String] = ["playable"]
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
        switch status {
        case .loaded:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
                playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
                self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                self.player?.isMuted = true
            }
            break
        case .failed:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("failde asset")
                //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
        case .cancelled:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("cancelled asset")
                //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT: 
While testing on physical device I get:

```
2018-04-12 16:30:50.653392+0300 App_Name[3543:1572246] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sync = syna;
}
```

Comment: Please specify "not working". Do you receive any errors? Or is the video simply not playing without any errors/warnings?

Comment: @DávidPásztor it is not showing, added possible error to post

Comment: Related Apple dev forum post: [AVPlayer Works on Simulator, but not on device](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88591)

Comment: @DávidPásztor tried both proposed on forum variants, neither of them helped

Comment: @Relorie did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because of the way you save the file locally what you are trying to play. In your device, your media file might not be accessible by your player. Please check your URL

Also, Try Playing any media file which is available on the server with http url and see if it works fine.

Also please make sure the HLS stream is served from https in case of server. If your stream url starts with http then please Allow Arbitrary Loads from your info.plist file. Otherwise it won't play any http stream.

```
<key>App Transport Security Settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to load local file, pathToStream string is a link to HLS.
e.g. https://stream.dpsu.gov.ua:5101/004_Shegini_rear/index.m3u8

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if your HLS url is http or https?

Comment: Can you please try playing some sample stream with same code and see if it working

Comment: Tried apple sample stream, it worked, but even if it's server side strange config I can't change it because it's a public source. Also, I've seen app with same streams working